# Is it possible to do bulk domain name expiration lookups?

Tags: domains

Does anyone know of a way to perform bulk-lookups on domain names and their expiration dates or whois information?  I'm thinking anywhere from 10 to 500 lookups at a time.

Answer (score 2):

I believe majority of hosting providers allow you to do batch lookup / reg. using CSV files. Unless I am mistaken, [DomainTools](http://whois.domaintools.com/) allows that as well once you have registered and logged in.

Regards,
Taavi